# Block outgoing connections to certain IP using PF

Tags: networking, firewall, pf, packet

Can someone give me a hint on how to setup a basic deny rule whenever any TCP request is sent to a specific IP address? I am using the **PF packet filter**. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most basic form would look like this, in your `/etc/pf.conf` config:

```
block from any to 192.0.2.2

# which is equivalent to:
block drop from any to 192.0.2.2
```

By default this `block` action will `drop` packets **silently** on all interfaces, from `any` source IP, in both directions. Because a client is unaware it is being blocked it will timeout and likely try again, and again...

`block return` is the *'friendly neighbor'* way to let the client know the address is unreachable by **responding** in a protocol specific way, with a *TCP RST (reset)* or *ICMP UNREACHABLE* packet. A client can use this information to give up, or try again in a sane way.

```
block return from any to 192.0.2.2
```

The default `block` behavior can be changed using the `set block-policy` option.

---

A more involved example - but easier to manage and read when your rule set starts to grow:

```
mybadhosts = "{ 192.0.2.2, 203.0.113.0/24 }"
ext_if = "em0"

block return on $ext_if from any to $mybadhosts                 # example #1
block return on em0 from any to { 192.0.2.2, 203.0.113.0/24 }   # ^expanded form

block drop out on egress from any to $mybadhosts                # example #2
```

**example #1** Shows simple use of variables, a list `{}`, a netmask `/24`, and specifies an interface `em0`. (Note variables are defined *without a $ sign*, and *quotes are removed*, when rules are expanded at runtime)

**example #2** Drops `out` outbound packets, on the `egress` interface group (see `ifconfig(8)`)

---

**See Also:**

- [OpenBSD Manual Pages - `pf.conf(5)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/pf.conf.5)
- [*OpenBSD PF Packet Filter User's Guide*](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/index.html)
- [*Firewalling with OpenBSD's PF packet filter* by Peter Hansteen](http://home.nuug.no/~peter/pf/en/)

Comment: @techraf I updated the answer to try and better clarify `return` behavior vs `drop`. thoughts?

Comment: I was trying to understand, now it's clear. Thanks.

Comment: `block` command line not found on OS X ????

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI the `block` command is not for your shell, if that is what you are trying. The syntax needs to be used in your `/etc/pf.conf`