# block command line not found

Tags: command-line, firewall, homebrew

I am trying to follow this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211034/63361) on OS X 11.x

```
block return from any to 192.0.2.2
```

The console displays :

> -bash: block: command not found

So, I tried to install it using brew:

```
brew install block
```

However, I got another error .

- How to install this firewall utility?

Comment: `block` is not a command; that is a line from the `pf` configuration file `/etc/pf.conf`

Comment: @user4556274 if you know how to use it on Mac OS X, please post an answer.

Comment: @derobert : my question is already about Mac OS X 10.11.6 El capitan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On recent versions of OS X, `pf` is installed and running by default.  The linked question is referring to changing the `pf` configuration, not installing a new utility.  Modifying a firewall on a production system is not something which should be done without reading the documentation (`man pf.conf` , `man pfctl`).

To add that `block` line (or experiment with other configuration changes), you would add it to the configuration file `/etc/pf.conf` with your preferred editor, and then reload the firewall configuration with

```
$ sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```